# jQuery - dialog will not close upon trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a dialog in an HTML page created as follows:

```
<div class="dialog" id="myID" style="display:block;z-index:1003;"abp="141"data-title="My Dialog">
    <!--Code for inside of div here...-->
</div>
```

I also have a script which, upon running, should close this dialog. It has the following line of code:

```
$('#myID').trigger('close');
```

I have debugged to be absolutely sure it is reaching this line, but when it gets to this line nothing appears to happen. I am sure it accesses the jQuery source files I have since I successfully use jQuery elsewhere in the program. If anyone has any ideas why this may be not working I'd be very appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: I tried using `dialog('close')` as well, VS gave an error "JavaScript runtime error:Oject doesn't support property or method 'dialog'"

Comment: This question doesn't stand by itself really well, we don't really know the context or what your event is. Do you have a listener for the close event? Trigger just kind of activates the event, but you still need the accompanying code somewhere else to actually hide the dialogue.

Comment: The code should work. As long as you initialize the dialog before calling close. I.e do not call close before opening. It is going to be syntax, mark up or conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The event name is prefixed with the widget name, so to trigger a dialog close event, run this:

```
$('#myID').trigger('dialogclose');
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it still stay open though :(